# Excel - display minutes, seconds and milliseconds with quotes and double quotes (i.e. mm"ss'xxx)

Tags: excel, time

is there a way to display a time formatted as mm:ss.xxx (xxx = milliseconds) in mm"ss'xxx as in motorsport time tables, while keeping the time values (because I need to add them)?

I.e. from 1:22.623 to 1"22'623

Comment: I don't think you can do that without including the decimal. `01"22'.623` seems possible with `mm\"ss'.000`

Comment: Yeah, it seems the decimal is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use a lookup table (hidden column) ... put your times into a column that you'll hide. Use the format given by Ron Rosenfield, then run a character replace on the .

A1 = time data

B1 = `SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"mm\""ss.000"), ".", "'")`